# Simple PHP form validation?

Tags: php, forms, validation

How would I go about validating the input (and not saving to file unless all three fields are filled correctly) of this code?

field1 = Name (first name and last name)

field2 = Text in the format of xxxx#1111

field3 = Email

```
if(isset($_POST['field1']) && isset($_POST['field2']) && isset($_POST['field3'])) {
  $data = $_POST['field1'] . '-' . $_POST['field2'] . '-' . $_POST['field3'] . "\n";
  $ret = file_put_contents('submissions.txt', $data, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
if($ret === false) {
  die('There was an error writing this file');
}
  else {
    echo "$ret bytes written to file";
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: tried anything? expecting the magic faeries to do it for you?

Answer (score 1):

The PHP function isset() only checks if the variable has been SET or not..

When you fill in the form and post it. Field 1, 2 and 3 will always be true because it containts an empty string.

The first thing you need to do, is to check if the fields are filled or not.. Use !empty() instead.

http://www.php.net/isset

Comment: Thank you! Will replace isset.

Answer (score 0):

```
$errors = array();
if (isset($_POST)){

if (!preg_match("/([\w\-]+\@[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/",trim($_POST['email'])))
  {
  $errors[] = "Invalid email format"; 
  }else{
  $email = trim(strip_tags($_POST['email']));
  }

if (strlen(trim($_POST['firstname])) <=0){
   {
  $errors[] = "Invalid firstname format"; 
  }else{
  $firstname = trim(strip_tags($_POST['firstname']));
  }
}
```

and so on

in the end

```
if count($errors)>0){ 'explode errors;}
```

otherwise process

i hope it helps you

Comment: why not `if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))`

Comment: there are many ways to validate.I think i dont need to show and tell all here .It is just an effort made by me to give the direction. I see earlier you just asked the guy not to expect any magic and now you have searched from php.net and just pasted your reply here